# How to put a list item inside a url?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to put my list item inside a string. It seems that when I insert an item from the list it comes out with brackets([]). Is their a way to get rid of these?

```
team = ['los-angeles-lakers']
    
url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/' + str(team) + '/stats'
print(url)
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
team_stats = df_list[0]
print(team_stats)
```

Comment: When the object is a list, then converting it to a string - ie. str(listobject) - will always result in the outcome that you're seeing.  On the other hand, str(listobject[0]) would give you the string of the first item in the list.  @PaulM.'s comment is valid - why have a list that only has a single string item?  Just have the string without the list.  (Although, I suspect you're working your way towards a list with mutiple items - in that case, if you want the value of a particular item, then you need to reference the item index.  Just because a list only contains one item, it's still a list)

Comment: That's an array not a list so it would be team[0] but my assumption is that you'll want to use as an array of multiple strings so you would need to iterate your array. 

for x in team:
  url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/' + team[x] + '/stats'
  etc

Comment: @MadisonCourto um, no **that is absolutely a `list`** not an array.

Comment: @MadisonCourto also, your loop is incorrect, and would result in a `TypeError`.

Comment: @MadisonCourto I'm not sure what you think that link demonstrates, but it certainly does not demonstrate that this is an array, and not a list, and it certainly doesn't demonstrate that your loop would not throw a TypeError (it will, because `team[x]` is trying to index a list with a string). Finally, w3schools is a notoriously bad resource. It's not even *correct* that Python doesn't have arrays. It does. Even its definition of array is incorrect "An array is a special variable, which can hold more than one value at a time".

Comment: @MadisonCourto lists and arrays **are not the same thing**. You wouldn't need to change the string type to a string. You would need to **not index your list with a string**, which is what `for x in team: team[x]` would do. And it would throw a TypeError, go ahead and test this yourself

Comment: You're correct sorry

Comment: I have been living in JS world for too long, I legit thought that was a simplification in Python, but obviously you still need to iterate based on index int.

Comment: This is only part of code, more items will be added but team[0] worked. Thanks @Craig

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on data structures and lists in python.

Let's say you have more than 1 item in the list:

`team_list = ['los-angeles-lakers', 'chicago-bulls', 'boston-celtics']`

To get the first item in the list, the string `'los-angles-lakers'`, you would reference index 0: `team_list[0]`. The Bulls are the second item, index 1, so `team_list[1]`, the Celtics, `team_list[2]`, and so on. You can also work backwards, by using `-`, but the last item is referenced by -1. So celtics `team_list[-1]`, bulls are `team_list[-2]`, lakers `team_list[-3]`. You can also use slicing on a list to select a specifc range of items, but you can look that up on your own.

You can also iterate through the list in a loop. See below:

```
team_list = ['los-angeles-lakers', 'chicago-bulls']

for team in team_list:    
    url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/' + str(team) + '/stats'
    print(url)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    team_stats = df_list[0]
    print(team_stats)
```